# How is this rest service URL formed?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I am learning this example:

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j

In this MovieRepository, this is the path setting:

```
collectionResourceRel = "movies", path = "movies".
```

Then why does the query have to contain a 'search' string:

```
// JSON object for single movie with cast
curl http://localhost:8080/movies/search/findByTitle?title=The%20Matrix
```

I thought it should be "curl http://localhost:8080/movies/findByTitle?title=The%20Matrix" without "search" in the http request. In all the files, I can't find any trace of "search". How does this happen?

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "movies", path = "movies")
public interface MovieRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Movie, Long> {

    Movie findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);

    Collection<Movie> findByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);

    @Query("MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) RETURN m,r,a LIMIT {limit}")
    Collection<Movie> graph(@Param("limit") int limit);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the [Spring Data REST documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting)

> To have your results sorted on a particular property, add a sort URL
>   parameter with the name of the property you want to sort the results
>   on. You can control the direction of the sort by appending a , to the
>   the property name plus either asc or desc. The following would use the
>   findByNameStartsWith query method defined on the PersonRepository for
>   all Person entities with names starting with the letter "K" and add
>   sort data that orders the results on the name property in descending
>   order:
>
> ```
> curl -v "http://localhost:8080/people/search/nameStartsWith?name=K&sort=name,desc"
> ```

Comment: Hi, Stdob, thanks for the info, but I am asking why there is a "search" appearing in the URL request. Please read my original question again. How does the 'search' occur in the URL?

Comment: I very carefully read your question: it's functionality in spring data rest `all query method resources are exposed under the resource search` [ https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/3.0.x/src/main/asciidoc/configuring-the-rest-url-path.adoc ]

Comment: That's great to know.